# java.util.Scanner: keeps waiting for additional input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Total Java newbie here.  Working on one of my very first Java programs.  Please help.
Here's what I am trying to achieve:
I need to accept user keyboard input of whitespace separated integers, copy them into an array and process them. KNOWN: user will enter only ONE line of data. I don't know how many numbers, but once they hit Enter, there won't be any more. As user input may contain words and special characters, I need to handle them with neat errors and prompt user to try again. When I run what I wrote below, I get in some kind of infinite loop where Scanner keeps waiting for additional input. How do I tell it it's over and there won't be any more input?

Here's the code:

```
<!-- language-all: java -->

public static void EnterInts () {

    System.out.println("Enter series of integers separated by whitespace. Press Enter key when finished.");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (input.hasNext()){
        if (input.hasNextInt(){
            int i = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Only integers can be entered. Try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should read the single line of input first, then create the Scanner to scan through that single line.

Try using a [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and [InputStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) to read the line first:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String str = in.readLine();
```

And then create the `Scanner`, perhaps passing a `StringBufferInputStream` created from the read string into its constructor.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I never used these classes before, so will need to take a look and see how they work. Copying/Pasting your code results in an error -- so need to do my due diligence.  Thanks for your help.